# Maximum matching contains one edge that contains a leaf of a tree.

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

I wanted to show the following using Berges Lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berge%27s_lemma): Let $T=(V,E)$ be a tree with $n:=|V| \geq 3$. Then any maximum matching $M_{max}$ contains at least one edge $E$ that contains one of the leafs of $T$.

Since $T$ is a tree it has at least two leafs $l_1,l_2$ and since $n \geq 3$ there is a path $P$ connecting $l_1$ to $l_2$ such that $|P| \geq 3$. If $M$ would not contain any edge $E$ with either $l_1 \in E$ or $l_2 \in E$, then $P$ would almost be an augmented path, in contradiction to Berge's Lemma. All I need is that $P$ is alternating, but I don't know whether it is possible to construct $P$ in this way.

Edit: After looking I found that something similar has been used in the proof of the tree theorem by Adam Lowrance in [$\alpha^{'}(G)\geq\frac{n}{1+\Delta(G)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2601230/alphag-geq-fracn1-deltag). However, he seems to use a different definition of augmented path than what is used in the wikipedia of Berges Lemma.

Comment: I think the proof in the question you linked to is just wrong on the point of the augmenting path. There is no guarantee in general that $P$ is augmenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The straightforward way to prove this claim is to just see what happens when we search for an augmenting path, starting at any unmatched vertex. (The starting vertex may or may not be a leaf; it doesn't matter. However, we may assume that some unmatched vertex to start from does exist: otherwise, $M_\max$ would be a perfect matching and cover every leaf.)

We will just alternate the following two steps:

1. From the current position, walk along an edge that's not part of $M_\max$.
2. From the current position, walk along an edge that *is* part of $M_\max$.

We will repeat these two steps until the step we're trying to do is impossible. Note that when we start at an unmatched vertex, the first step should always be possible: when $n \ge 2$, every vertex has at least one edge, and if it's unmatched, then that edge is not part of $M_\max$.

How can we get stuck? There are two options:

1. We get stuck on step 1: we went to the current vertex along an edge that is part of $M_\max$, but now there are no edges out of it that are not part of $M_\max$. Then our current vertex must be a leaf that's covered by the matching, and we have what we wanted.
2. We get stuck on step 2: we went to the current vertex along an edge that is not part of $M_\max$, but now there are no edges out of it that *are* part of $M_\max$. Then the current vertex is also unmatched, and the path we walked is an $M_\max$-augmenting path, which is a contradiction to Berge's lemma.

Crucially, because the graph is a tree, we must get stuck: there are no cycles, so we can't keep walking forever.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand you correctly, I can start on a leaf and then I obtain a path that has to end on a leaf that is contained in an edge in $M_{max}$, right? Hence the claim of the linked post should be true, right? Im asking because of your comment above.

Comment: It *is* true that there is such a path starting and ending at a leaf. What I meant in my comment above was just that if we take an arbitrary path starting and ending at an unmatched leaf, there is no guarantee that it's an augmenting path.

Comment: I see, however, as far as I can tell the existence is all that is needed! Thank you so much.

Comment: What happens if I start with an unmatched vertex $v$, do $1$, then do $2$ and then get stuck. Then I have a vertex $v_1$ which is a leaf, however it might be that $v$ is also a leaf, leaving me with a path that connects two leaves and has no edge that does not contain a leaf. What I want is a path that has an edge that does not belong to $M$ and does not contain a leaf, which I would have with the path in the question. Is there a way out?

Comment: Did you get stuck on step 1 or on step 2? Its unclear from your explanation. Either way, you get an augmenting path in only one case, but in the other you get a leaf that's covered by the matching - this is what you wanted all along! (I'm not sure why you specifically want an augmenting path with an edge that does not contain a leaf.)

Comment: Not quiet, I want to have a path such that I can conclude that there has to be an edge $E$ that is not incident to a leaf and is not in the matching. This is what the argument is for and I think that your method does not work in this specific case, does it? The problem may be that I worded my question badly/too imprecise and I apologize, if that is the case.

Comment: That's a completely different question :( Your question asks to show that there is an edge $E$ that *is* in the matching and *does* contain one of the leaves...

Comment: Yes, I fear that I may have been imprecise, I am sorry... In the text below the question (where I explain the steps I made) I shouldve written that this is the method I wanted to use. Its my bad and your answer to the question the way I wrote it is perfectly fine, I am sorry.

Comment: Then the method you want to use does not work. I can guarantee you an augmenting path, which contradicts Berge's lemma; I cannot guarantee you an augmenting path with this extra weird property, because there are cases where it does not exist.

Comment: Alright. Thinking of the linked post I gave, the argument should then be incorrect, right? If I understand you correctly, such a path need not exist.

Comment: The argument in that question can be made to work, but it's worded confusingly. I would rephrase it as: take an arbitrary path of length $\ge 3$ from one leaf to another leaf. If it has at least four edges $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4, \dots$, then either $e_2$ or $e_3$ is the edge we want: they can't both be in $M$, and neither contains a leaf. If the path has only three edge $e_1, e_2, e_3$, then $e_2$ is the edge we want, unless it's in $M$. Finally, if the path has three edges and $e_2 \in M$, **then** it is an augmenting path, and we contradict Berge's lemma.

Comment: Thank you so much!